# Laravel - Calculate percentage increase or decrease in users from last 30 days

Tags: php, laravel

do you have an idea how to get a percentage as in the picture

[image: picture]

my code

```
 $dateFrom = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
        $dateTo = Carbon::now();
        $monthly = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])->count();
        $previousDateFrom = Carbon::now()->subDays(60);
        $previousDateTo = Carbon::now()->subDays(31);
        $previousMonthly = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$previousDateFrom, $previousDateTo])->count();
        if ($previousMonthly < $monthly) {
            if ($previousMonthly > 0) {
                $percent_from = $monthly - $previousMonthly;
                (int)  $percent = $percent_from / $previousMonthly * 100; //increase percent
            } else {
                (int) $percent = 100; 
            }
        } else {
            $percent_from = $previousMonthly - $monthly;
            (int) $percent = $percent_from / $previousMonthly * 100; 
        }
```

any suggestion?

Comment: what is the input/output of your code?

Comment: Wouldn't `$difference = (($current_month_count - $past_month_count) / $past_month__count) * 100;`  do? if its negative then its decreasing and increasing if positive

Comment: I saw [your question on laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-calculate-percentage-increase-or-decrease-in-users-from-last-30-days?page=1&replyId=773526) where you got a suitable answer. Do you mind closing this if that one has worked for you?